Truth tables. What does a truth valuation of a formula even mean?
What does a truth table even mean? Does anyone actually spell it out anywhere? (reference please). People feel like the are not taught rigorously like limits are.
Edit: What does it mean for a (non-tautological) formula (i.e. p ⇒ q)  to have truth valuation?
I've came up my own formulation. You partition the universe by the rows of the truth table. A proposition is True iff all the partitions corresponding to False rows are empty.



p
q
p ⇒ q




T
T
T


T
F
F


F
T
T


F
F
T



An aside
I believe I got through the education system by evolving mental models that gave me the right grades on tests rather than actually using rigorous, logical thought (by watching live streaming I am more exposed to these people now). The end result was that I was a terrible tutor because I would just spit out my mental model which wouldn't actually help the student understand. Truth tables remind me of my mental models. They have no context.
Old formulation
You have a universe which you can partition such that p and q have the same value in each of the partitions. Then p ⇒ q is true iff the only combinations of p and q for all the partitions are p=T,q=T, p=F,q=T, p=F,q=F (i.e. p=T,q=F corresponding to (p ⇒ q)=F never occurs).

A truth table is just a convenient way to present theorems in propositional logic. You may find helpful my recent posting on truth tables at https://www.quora.com/profile/Dan-Christensen-8 Of course, this can only be fully understood if you have some knowledge of the rules of inference in propositional logic. When first introducing students to propositional logic, a bit of hand waving with truth tables seem unavoidable.

I think trying to formalize what a truth table is somewhat analogous to trying to formalize the roster method for representing (certain) sets, or perhaps better yet, trying to formalize the table method for representing (certain) functions. The reason for "better yet" is that it seems to me that a truth table is essentially the table method for representing all valuations of the well-formed-formula under consideration.

@DaveLRenfro Yes its a function! So my question really is what does it mean for a (non-tautological) formula to have truth valuation. In propositional logic, there are no quantifiers, and formulas are built from propositional variables using logical connectives  I feel without quantifiers you are just doing abstract nonsense. Or rather, first you need to suppose some structure (a roster set of combinations of valuations), then on that structure a formula can have a truth valuation (true iff the function is never false).

I think the partition-the-universe model is pragmatic, provided you have a sufficiently robust universe. For instance, if the universe consists only of polynomials, then the properties of continuity and differentiability are indistinguishable from merely being a member of the universe.

@user1815 in that case only one of you rows (combinations of valuations) is non-empty.

From your comment I think the following MSE questions/answers are relevant: Does mathematics become circular at the bottom? What is at the bottom of mathematics? AND Is logic circular at the basic level? AND Foundation of Formal Logic AND How to study first order logic, without the use of sets?. Also, in mathoverflow see The sets in mathematical logic.

I will take a pedagogical approach that aims to help the student build a conception of how truth tables are connected to their ordinary reasoning. In the second part, I hope to show how the truth functions might arise in a natural way. We'll take ordinary logical reasoning for granted. We'd like to see how truth tables relate to reasoning. The idea, we are told, is that the truth tables should be a rigorous model of propositional reasoning. The rigor comes from clear and consistent rules for calculating truth values. But how is the model related to what it purports to be modelling? While many authors present the truth value or truth-value function of well-formed formulas clearly, few (none in introductory texts I've found) discuss the connection with reasoning and proofs.
First off, for the point in the opening paragraph about the rigor of proofs by truth table, one needs a theorem like the following:

Given two well-formed formulas, they have identical truth tables iff each can be deduced from the other.

By "deduced," I mean deduced using formal logic. In many symbolic procedures like this and algebra, the mind tends to focus on the rules of operation and lose sight of the meaning. This theorem says something about what the result means: the truth-value function is a sort of "hash code" that can be compared to the code of another expression. One could extend the theorem above:

Given two well-formed formulas $\scr A$ and $\scr B$, if whenever the truth value of $\scr A$ is true, truth value of $\scr B$ is true, then $\scr B$ can be deduced from  $\scr A$.

Whatever the level of explanation or proof that accompanies such statements, they establish a practical meaning of the truth-value function.
A second way to see how logic is connected to truth functions is as follows. This is nearly the same as the OP's partition-the-universe idea, but it is presented below as an exercise.
Consider two predicates $P(t)$ and $Q(t)$. For instance, we could take the classic $P(t) =$  "it is raining" and $Q(t) =$ "it is cloudy" or "the ground is wet." Here, implicitly, $t =$ the current time. Unless you really mean it only for the immediate present, in which case they will know you're a mathematician, since a normal person would say, "It's cloudy and raining." Or maybe just, "At least it's not raining." Or "Gosh, it's nice out." Depending on the weather. The pedagogical point is that your students, at least at the beginning of the course, are normal people, and on that foundation, you're trying to help them build a more sophisticated understanding of logic. Tell a student, "Right now, if rainy, then cloudy," they might wonder why math bothers with IF-THEN at all, since right now, such an IF-THEN is either an AND or AND-NOT.  I generally stick to mathematical examples if possible, since then you do not get people objecting, "What about sereins?", and other words you've never heard of.
So we might take $P(f) =$ "the function $f$ is continuous at $0$" and $Q(f) =$ "the function $f$ is differentiable at $0$."
Or $P(x) =$ "$x^2 > 5$" and $Q(x) =$ "$x > 5$." Next consider which combinations of true and false are possible for the truth values of the pair $(P,Q)$. Make a table, where $\blacksquare$ means there are examples of the combination and $\square$ means the combination does not occur:



$P(x) \setminus Q(x)$
True
False




True
$\blacksquare$
$\blacksquare$


False
$\square$
$\blacksquare$



Next try to describe when the combinations exist. There generally will be several answers. One or two will seem simplest, like, "IF $Q(x)$, THEN $P(x)$" or "$P(x)$ OR NOT-$Q(x)$."
This exercise, instead of defining the meaning a connective or formula via a truth-value function, shows how truth-value functions characterize the relationship between two propositions and at the same time how the relationship can be expressed logically.
Finally, explaining the truth value on actual propositions tends to elude me, as we saw with the "right now" statement. A proposition is by definition exactly one of the two, either true or false. It's not sometimes one and sometimes the other. So how to make sense of these:

IF 2 is even, THEN 3 is negative.
IF 2 is odd, THEN 3 is negative.

If someone comes up to you and tells either of these things to you, what are you to think? The proper things to say are "There's no if about it: 2 is even" and "Whatever you say, 3 is positive." The component propositions need no logical connective. Yet each of the two statements above has a truth value, but is that their meaning, merely "false" and "true"? While the statements may be ridiculous, it must be the case that they are not nonsense. I guess. Though in the second one, would you want to argue with someone who begins with a false premise?

Whenever 2 is odd, 3 is negative. This is obviously not a false statement, however absurd it may seem.

@TomHuntington Or "If 2 were odd, then 3 would be negative." English fortunately provides the subjunctive mood precisely to allow us to discuss counterfactuals.

If 2 were odd, then there would be an integer $k$ with $2k+1 = 2$.  We can manually check that $k = -1, 0, 1$ do not work.  If $k > 1$ then $2k+1 > 3$, so no positive value of $k$ works.  Thus $k < -1$.  So $ 3 = 2 + 1 = 2k+2 < 0$.

I have often wondered if there is anyway to formalize the idea that we can always find a "reasonable" path like this from one false supposition to another false conclusion.

From the formal standpoint, truth tables are just the tabular representations of the Boolean functions (usually of 1 or 2 variables). You will, probably, find nothing mysterious about writing the statement that the price of a bottle of water on a cold day is \$1 and on a hot day \$5 and the price of a bottle of lemonade is \$3 and \$10 respectively in the form
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{water} & \text{cold day} & 1\text{ dollar}
\\
\text{water} & \text{hot day} & 5\text{ dollars}
\\
\text{lemonade} & \text{cold day} & 3\text{ dollars}
\\
\text{lemonade} & \text{hot day} & 10\text{ dollars}
\end{array}
$$
and, I hope, your students will understand that table too (if not, I recommend going over it first before switching to any more abstract objects).
The standard Boolean operations "NOT", "AND" and "OR" out of which everything else can be constructed, are just functions of Boolean arguments (1 for "NOT" and 2 (or even more) for the other two). The truth tables merely list all possible values of the arguments together with the result. So the row $true\mid false\mid false$ in the "AND" truth table merely means that if $A$ is true and $B$ is false, then $A\&B$ is false, neither less, nor more.
The meaning of the truth tables is not something difficult. What is difficult is to convey the relation between the formal Boolean "NOT", "AND" and "OR" and, especially, "IMPLIES" (which in the standard Aristotelian logic is just an abbreviation of $(\neg A)\vee B$). It usually takes not too much time for the kids to understand the negation of a statement without quantifiers, a bit longer time to realize how to properly translate usual language "AND" and "OR" (or but) into the formal language, especially if more than two variables are involved. Consider, say, the sentence "We will pay your a bonus if you do all your usual work and make some extra contribution to the project but not if you violate the safety rules". The first "AND" is easy, but the proper translation of "but not if" may cause some trouble, so it makes sense to play with such 3 variable common language sentences and the corresponding Boolean formulas. By the way, the truth tables may be helpful here because to make the truth table of 8 rows with variables A="work is done", B="extra contribution is made" and C="safety rules are violated" and the output "bonus is paid" is not too hard and checks if the statement is interpreted correctly, and the formal Boolean expression in terms of A,B,C is an adequate translation if and only if its truth table agrees with the intended meaning of the sentence. The "only if" part is self-evident, but it is worth emphasizing the "if" part here too: even if the formula doesn't look like a "natural" translation of the sentence, but the truth tables agree, it is a correct translation because the intended meaning is exactly the same.
The discussion of the "IMPLIES" operation and its correspondence to the common language constructs like "if ...,then ...", "... unless ...", "... only if ...", etc., etc., is quite a topic in itself. I haven't dealt with teaching small kids for quite a long time, so while I remember that it is the most difficult part of the story, I'd rather leave proposing good recipes to someone else here (that is unless you are severely restricted by time, in which case the authoritarian approach along the lines "Just memorize that if $A$ is false, then $A$ implies $B$ no matter what $B$ is!" may be your only feasible option).
Just my two cents :-)

I like the formulation B is true wherever A is true. This is obviously true whenever A is false.

I guess my question was: What does it mean for A and B to be true? A or B, A implies B to be true? Answer: the non-existence of the false rows of the truth table.

@TomHuntington Answer: the non-existence of the false rows of the truth table I'm not sure what you mean by that. The full truth table for "AND" contains 3 rows with the "false" outcome, but that doesn't mean that $A&B$ is never true. Can you express this thought of yours in a formally correct and unambiguous way?

You could have a universe for each possible combination (water, hot-day) , (water, cold-day) , (lemonade, hot-day) , (lemonade, cold-day). The statement water ⇒ hot-day is only true in universes where the state (water, cold-day)  does not occur (i.e. rows in the truth table where water ⇒ hot-day is false are not inhabited. i.e. "the row doesn't exist in the universe")

@TomHuntington Ah, you try to define the meaning of some statement being true (i.e., to hold for all instances) in some particular "universe" in terms of the truth table for that statement? Then yes, your description makes perfect sense. Just think carefully about how to put it in words when conveying the idea to the students because even I had trouble understanding you initially and keep in mind that while this is what truth tables can be used for, it isn't what they are. By themselves, they don't know whether their rows are inhabited or not; they just list all logically possible cases.

Tom:

You are actually asking a math question more than a math ed question.  "What is the rigorous definition of a truth table".  It's a Booleian Algebra question, I guess.  (I donno...only had the smattering of that, that you get in EE survey course.)  This isn't to say, "neener, neener", like a rules-based moderator algorithm.  It's to make you think about your own frame, what matters to you.

But addressing the actual math ed issue you raise:  You are making the classic, classic mistake of thinking that you should first teach a more rigorous version of a topic.  We see this all the time, with the "do Rudin first, while teaching calculus to mediocre students" questioners/advocates--I have seen people literally recommending Spivak to a student that said he was struggling with Stewart and wanted a crutch/crib for that.  Even for students that eventually do go to needing the most rigorous emphasis, this is not the optimal order for learning (and please, be aware the VAST majority, probably over 90%, never do).  At it's extreme, it would involve teaching Peano (piano?) Axioms to toddlers.

I have done fine throughout my life with a model of a truth table as just organizing all the outcome combinations of independent events.  I am not a mathematician, but someone who has done physical science, a bit of EE, etc.  (I.e.  like most of your students.)



"organizing all the outcome combinations of independent events" this is equivalent to partitioning the universe

Tom, "independent events" (amount not specified), is not equal to "all independent events".  Also, "universe" can be a very pliable term...do we mean "the" universe?  Or the problem situation universe?  But...interesting  in any case, that you had a  neener-neener logic/math comment, not a math ed one.  Ed, ed, ed!

Truth tables are taught as a hermeneutic. But this is mathematics. The pedagogy should be rigorous not hermeneutical. Asking for a rigorous pedagogy is a real question. Even if mine probably didn't make the cut, lol

As other comments and answers have said, either implicitly or explicitly: these "propositional calculus" variables "$p$" and "$q$" are indeed variables, just as the traditional "$x$" for a "real variable". Yes, we may ask what exactly this means!!! As a first approximation to a rigorous notion of "variable...", and asking about the "truth value" of an assertion $f(p,q)=$ true, ... or $f(x)=5$, ... we can probably determine that for some values of the variables $p,q,x$ the assertion is true, and for some values it is false.
The "truth table" approach is simply a relatively short, but exhaustive, consideration of all the possible true/false values of the true/false "variables" $p,q$, etc.
This sort of exhaustive listing of possibilities is much harder when the "variables" are "real variables", or others, where there is/are a large (possibly infinite) number of possible values. :)

Maybe starting with a modified truth table would help:

Then transition to the more standard presentation with T's and F's.
BTW, you might avoid some confusion about implications by emphasizing, for example, that "it is raining" implies "it is cloudy" simply rules out the possibility that it is currently raining and not cloudy.
On its own, P implies Q does not mean that P causes Q, or that Q is always true when P is true.

EDIT
Line 1 of the OP's truth table, for example, comes from the theorem, (A & B) => (A => B). It is formally proven here using a form of natural deduction, which is the basis for most, if not all of modern mathematics.

We can as easily justify each of the other lines of the truth table with similar proofs no longer than 8 lines:
https://www.dcproof.com/ImpliesLine1.html (as above)
https://www.dcproof.com/ImpliesLine2.html
https://www.dcproof.com/ImpliesLines3-4.html

"A truth table is just a convenient way to present theorems in propositional logic". I get that you are playing a game with certain rules. It's just how do you apply the findings of this game to other areas of mathematics. Maybe it's just abstract non-sense (obviously not, but no one tries to formulate the application rigorously)

@TomHuntington There is nothing "nonsensical" about it. See my edit.

I said "obviously not". I what I meant is you can play these games with certain well defined rules, like p-adic numbers which I consider abstract nonsense since they have no application.

@TomHuntington Here, I have rigorously formulated the truth table for IMPLIES in terms of the rules of inference of classical propositional logic.

Sorry I understand now, never heard of modified truth tables. Deriving the values of the formula in the truth table, wasn't what I was getting hung up on. Truth tables for and, or, implies are definitional for me. Picking the column of truth values defines you a formula. I didn't think there was any need to prove them (Isn't such a proof circular, begging the question, since you are using implication in the proof). You just need to convince yourself that the spelling they are given actually corresponds to what the word in English actually means.

@TomHuntington This modified truth table was just something I concocted. Not sure it is all that valuable. Teachers can judge for themselves. The truth tables for NOT, AND, OR  and IMPLIES are usually used as informal "definitions" for beginners. When students are able to write simple formal proofs (for math majors only?), it should be obvious that the entries in the truth tables can be formally justified using common rules of inference. The rules of inference that "define" implication are those for (1) conditional proof (to introduce '=>') and (2) detachment (to eliminate '=>')....

... Using these rules and the rules for AND, OR and NOT, we can derive theorems to justify each line of the truth table as well as (A => B) <=> ~[A & ~B] (another common "definition" of IMPLIES).

@TomHuntington, by the way, p-adic numbers have many "applications", ... The fact that they seem to be "defined" capriciously is just an artifact of the standard curriculum, which finds it easier to contrive a different metric on $\mathbb Q$ than to talk about (very meaningful!) projective limits of $\mathbb Z/p^n$... This is how p-adic numbers and adeles arise in String Theory in physics, for example.
